# References for the source and application of bonding-antibonding splitting on electronic structure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I am currently doing research on semiconductor materials, so I need a very strong background in band theory to understand the literature. I am currently trying to understand the relationship between bonding-antibonding splitting and the formation of the band energy gap in solids. What are some good references on how bonding-antibonding splitting comes about, and what its implications are in the electronic structure of solids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous excellent reviews out, two that come to mind are:

[R. Hoffmann in Angew Chem Int Ed Engl, 26, 846](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.198708461/abstract)

[R. Hoffmann in Rev Mod Phys, 60, 601](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v60/i3/p601_1)